# Make sourced .bash_profile works immediately in current window

Tags: terminal, bash, ssh

I use a macOS to connect to an Ubuntu server, after defining new .bash_profile (like upgrading node.js or making new alias), I will have to exit the ssh and login again after sourcing the .bash_profile before the updated bash to take effect is it possible to refresh the session in current terminal ssh session?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with Apple software or hardware. It is to so with the software on the Ubuntu server

Comment: The question also appears on Ask Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/q/1085552/10127

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can refresh the settings by running

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

This will reread (source) the file.

Also `bash` caches paths to binaries, so if you change the location of a binary already known to `bash` you need to run

```
hash -r
```

to remove those references.

Comment: @aeroxy `source` and `.` are synonyms in `bash`...

Comment: Then that's very strange.

Comment: @aeroxy What does `type source` return? What is the error message you get when running `source ~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: No error message, it just doesn't work. For example if I upgraded Node and update the path and then I source ~/.bash_profile I got the same "node -v" as before and I must exit the terminal and reopen it before it takes effect. I got "source is a shell builtin" from type source.

Comment: @aeroxy Ahh. See edit then :-)

Comment: @aeroxy You are welcome! If you want to see which paths currently are cached just run `hash` without any parameters.